# Will a focal length reducer help me image deep sky objects using an 8" newtonian telescope?

Tags: focal-length, image-quality, astrophotography

Will a 0.5x focal length reducer help me to reduce the exposure time if I am imaging deep sky objects? I'm using a 1200mm focal length optical tube (f/6), a 32mm super view telephoto extension eyepiece, and a Nikon D5500 (sensor size of 23.5x 15.6mm). I do not have a computerised mount.

If the focal length reducer can help, then how will it help me? Or is there any other way I can reduce my exposure time to 15 or 20 seconds?

**Addendum:**
For now, I connect a 32mm superview projection eyepiece directly to the DSLR's T2 thread and place it into the focuser. This should give me a wide view and maybe 10 to 15 sec exposures can be taken...would this be possible?

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: 15-20s is a very short exposure time for most DSOs. Exposure times for these are usually measures in minutes or even hours. What exposure times are you currently using that you wish to get down to such a short time? Are you stacking images and without a computerised/motorised mount, how are you compensating for movement (from the Earth's rotations)?

Answer (score 3):

If the object is at fixed distance, has fixed size (and is moving at constant angular speed) and fits frame well: no, you cannot get better photograph of it with focal length reducer.

Focal length reducer has three effects:

1. it makes image brighter
2. it reduces the number of pixels which object occupies
3. if it contains glass it looses some small amount of light

1 is totally negated by 2 (and 3). Motion blur remains the same in relation to object size, you do get visibly less motion blur but it becomes just the same if you crop the photograph to frame obtained without reducer.

You can only get a better photograph of fixed size & distance object if you increase the entrance pupil, or prolong the exposure (with motorized mount).

If the object is larger than the frame with current setup, you will benefit from reducer for sure, but not if the object fits the frame well already.

---

[Chris](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/44828/chris) suggested that you could try stacking of multiple images to either compensate for noise in underexposed images to maintain the maximum usable exposure time or to improve good exposures even more - if the object is considerably smaller than the sensor. Removing noise improves percepted resolution as well. What you could do is: take a series of exposures withing tolerable exposure time and then merge them with some shifting using visible anchor points.

However, I haven't practiced it and I cannot give good software recommendation. It sure can be done manually in GIMP though.

Comment: What would be the best entrant pupil size i can get..??? Although id love to own a motorised mount but cant afford one at the moment. :( @Euripinhollow

Comment: @dwayne-dias: entrant pupil size is focal length divided by F-number. In your case it is 1200/6=200mm. You can only get bigger entrant pupil with another telescope.

Comment: So should this b good rnough for deep space imaging..?? For now i connect a 32mm superview projection eyepiece directly to to the t2 thread of my dslr and place it into the focuser. This should give me a wide view. And as calculated i may b able to tske 10 to 15 sec exposures. Would this b possible...???

Comment: I guess its best learned and understood once experimented :) @euripinhollow.

Comment: @dwayne-dias: yes, you'd better try it. If the object is larger than the frame with current setup, you will benefit from reducer for sure, but not if the object fits the frame well already.

Comment: Thanx for all your help @euripinhollow... :)

Comment: @steve-ives: if you reduce the exposure with same entrant pupil you will introduce more noise in relation to the object which you photograph. The benefit from the brightness increase is already compensated with that the object occupies proportionally less area. I have written all of it in the answer.

Comment: Another if would be (just for completeness): If the object is considerably smaller than the sensor, you could try stacking of multiple images to either compensate for noise in underexposed images to maintain the maximum usable exposure time or to improve good exposures even more. It could even improve resolution.

Comment: @chris: sure. You'd better make it an answer because I cannot add it to my answer because of lack of experience with stacking shifted images. I was not taking stacking into account at all, just speaking inside the scope defined by the author.

Comment: @EuriPinhollow The skope of the question is the reason I don't want to make it a full answer as well. When it's gone due to comment deletions, it's gone, unless you on somebody else adds it as side note to a proper answer (as yours). But from the question I get that its author did not consider this option, therefore I thought it is a useful hint.